# Why do some stocks gain or lose a particular percentage of their value?

Tags: stocks, shares

I've seen many stocks rising only 4.99%, 9.98% per day, but I've not seen them rising like 4.56%, 10.43% or anything like this. It looks like someone is making it sure that they don't rise above some particular limit. Who does this? And some of these stocks have really high volumes making it not possible for promoters to buy or sell their shares to rectify extra percentage of rise or fall.

Here are some of such stocks:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm a noob so if possible please explain this in the easiest way. Thank! :)

Comment: At a quick glance those look like very illiquid stocks (few buyers/sellers) so it is possible that the small number of traders are trading at a specific percentage gain/loss (e.g. trailing % limit orders or systematic purchases).

Comment: Beyond D Stanley's postulation, keep in mind that coincidences exist, and correlation does not imply causation. You should be sure you understand what stock prices actually 'mean', and if you are trading a stock so illiquid that you believe a single entity is setting the price, then keep in mind how much risk is in play for such a stock.

Answer (score 3):

This observation is interesting but I don't think there is **statistical significance**. To check, go to NASDAQ website and view the top gainers of today. I just did this and I am seeing numbers including *11.55%, 13.63%* and so on.

There are observations that many stock **prices (not percentages)** close on round figures. The reason is people willing to sell at round numbers. Please someone correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a finite sample.  If you do the calculation on all of the traded stocks each day over a period of time then you will see a normal distribution of price.  No one manipulates a stock's price so that it achieves an "X" percent gain per day.